# group by then annotate following relationships backwards in django

Tags: django, group-by, django-annotate

I can sum all payments for each Klient. But I need to know sum each type of payment.

Here are my models:

```
class Klient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

```
class Platba(models.Model):
    PAYMENT = 'P'
    GIFT = 'G'
    TYPE = [
        (PAYMENT, 'Patment'),
        (GIFT, 'Gift'),
    ]


    when = models.DateField()
    ammount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    klient = models.ForeignKey(
        Klient, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="payments"
    )
    type = models.CharField(
        'Kind of payments',
        max_length=1,
        choices=TYPE,
        default=PAYMENT,
    )
```

here is annotate for each klient and summing all payments, then print

```
all = Klient.objects.annotate(Sum("payments__ammount"))

for k in all:
     print(k, " -> ", k.payments__ammount__sum)
```

but I would like to get sum for each TYPE of Platba.
so I can accesss like `k.payments_p` for Platba.PAYMENT and `k.payments_g` for Platba.GIFT

if I do

```
Klient.objects.values("id", "payments__type").annotate(Sum("payments__ammount"))
```

then I get two rows for each klient and that is not what I want.

thanks for help or tip

Answer (score 0):

aha, I should do more reading manual ;-)
it is [conditional-aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation) what I need

and also I did find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68961822/5706766) helpfull, thanks